# Matplotlib Bar Plot Grouping Subplots

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I'm currently generating this plot:

[image]

But as you can see, it is taking taking the items from arrays below and spreading them across the xticks.

```
[array([ 1.77009257,  1.57980963,  0.31896943,  0.01874767]), array([ 1.02788175,  0.99604306])]

[array([ 0.20091287,  0.14682076,  0.03212798,  0.00187477]), array([ 0.09545977,  0.11318596])]
```

What I want is to create a cluster of all four items from the first array over the xtick -2wks and a cluster of the two items of the next array over xtick -1wk.

Bonus points if you can then give each bar in a given cluster the corresponding label from these arrays.

```
[Index([u'AL GAINESVILLE LOCK', u'AL GREENSBORO', u'AL HIGHLAND HOME', u'AL BREWTON 3 SSE'],dtype='object', name=u'StateCity'), Index([u'AL GREENSBORO', u'AL GAINESVILLE LOCK'], dtype='object', name=u'StateCity')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be best off using `pandas` `plot` for this. The second example [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots) looks very similar to what you would like to achieve if I understand you correctly.

If you transpose your data so that the `index` you show below makes up the `columns` and your `xticks` make up the new `index`, you should get what you are looking for.

Comment: I thought about this approach, but I was wondering if there was a more modular way to handle it because I don't think it would handle the case were there isn't a value for some of the columns in DF.  As illustrated in my example arrays.

Comment: I believe `pandas` fills in zero, ie, no bar, for missing values: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-with-missing-data